# Is there an Explicit or Recursive Formula for $3, 3, 5, 8, 11$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I was working on a problem where I needed to cube a sequence of integers to sum to $2022$ in as few moves as possible. The only possible way that I found was $3, 3, 5, 8, 11$ (although I could be completely wrong).

After cubing each term:
$27 + 27 + 125 + 512 + 1331 = 2022$

I'm not sure my sequence $3, 3, 5, 8, 11 $ is the correct one but if it is, I'm completely at a loss to describe it since it is not arithmetic, geometric or fibonacci. The only thing I noticed is that the 1st term and 3rd term sum to the 4th. Likewise the 2nd and 4th sum to the 5th. But that could just be a coincidence I suppose.

Any suggestions for me?

Comment: I wouldn't expect much of a pattern here...it very much depends on the choice of $2022$.  I expect the "best" choice might be quite random looking.

Comment: I don't understand why it is not adequate to describe a sequence of five integers by listing the five integers.

Comment: If you want a longer sequence, I think you need to first assign meaning to what the sequence would represent.  For example, what would the next term represent?  Possibly the shortest sequence to get to 2023??

Comment: $3,3,5,8,11$ is the shortest sequence.

Comment: @jjagmath, thanks for the affirmation! I'm relieved that I didn't botch the sequence up!

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the comments! Perhaps finding a formula is outside the scope of the question although I thought it might be necessary since I basically used trial and error to arrive at my answer. I will check with my teacher to see if this is sufficient. Thanks again!

Comment: I agree with other comments, trying to find a pattern in such a small sequence doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Shorter sequences may be possible if you allow negative integers (which are indeed integers).

Comment: @paw88789 that did occur to me but I didn't find a sequence including negative numbers that was shorter than the one I already had when I first started checking. That doesn't mean that there isn't one, just that I haven't found one yet. I guess I'll keep checking to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: I've found some of length three using a computer search, including $(-37)^3+(-13)^3+38^3$

Comment: $(3,3,5,8,11)$ appears in OEIS nine times. Have a look

Comment: @paw88789 Thank you so much! You have been a huge help!

Answer (score 1):

*Just a possible idea*

In $OEIS$ sequence $A082602$ is *"the number of primes between successive Fibonacci numbers (including possibly the Fibonacci numbers themselves)"*.

Given the context, this could be interesting.

There is no formula or even approximation.